# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method not called for a nested table view inside a cell under iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a table view with custom cells loaded from a nib file. Inside each custom cell I have a child table view rotated to scroll horizontally. The custom parent cell's class is the data source and delegate for the child table view. In iOS 6, when tapping on my child cells I used to have my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in the custom cell class called. In iOS7 no taps reach the child table view's delegate anymore, I can't scroll it and when I tap inside it only the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of the parent table view is called. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a collection view?

Comment: @GuyKogus, yes I would have used it instead but the business currently need to support iOS 5, too. Can't do much about that

Comment: Oh yes you can :) https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView We used this a lot at my old workplace. It's awesome!

Comment: @GuyKogus, Thank you about pointing me to this project. I will play with it and see If I can make use of it :-)